# MongoDB remove element out array with index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have an array in a mongodb collection and want to remove one element from it with the index, didnt found how to make it, or an operator for it...

document example:

```
    {
    "_id": "<someID>",
    "array": [
      {
        "elemt": 1
      },
      {
        "elemt": 2,
      },
      {
        "elemt": 2,
      }]
    }
```

(duplicates can occur - and dont want to delete these duplicates)

and i want to achive that an element can be removed with the index of it...

Using:

- NodeJS 8.9
- Mongodb 3.4
- (npm) mongodb (native)
- Visual Studio 17

Comment: It's not very clear... Do you want to remove duplicate element from your array? Or do you want to remove the element at a specific index of the array ?

Comment: i want to remove an element with the index of it, and not to remove duplicates, with that i meant: duplicates can occur - and dont want to delete these duplicates

Comment: didnt found this before, thanks, but now: how to insert the index? i cant use the templated strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a 2-step solution to achieve what you described.

1. Set your array's element to `null`
2. Find `null` element and `$pull` it from your array.

   ```
   db.collection.update({}, {$unset : {"array.2" : 1 }});
   db.collection.update({}, {$pull : {"array" : null }});
   ```

   You can specify the `_id` in the query. You can't use string templates to specify the index in your query. It will throw out an error **"Unexpected template string"**.
   You can use computed property:

   ```
   var arrIndex = `array.${index}`;
   /* ... */
   db.collection.update({}, {$unset : {[arrIndex] : 1 }});
   ```

or just wrap your string literal in brackets `[]`, like this: `[array.${index}]`.

Comment: thanks, but now: how to insert the index? i cant use the templated strings?

Comment: How are you trying to achieve this? What's the problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hasezoey/662822b900baeb01a880b03bef223704 here it says "Unexpected template string"

Comment: can you set it into variable earlier in the code and then use it?

Comment: I updated the answer based on the data you provided.

Comment: thanks! putting it in `[]` worked, didnt knowed that... ^^